# ¿Cómo saber qué arquitectura tiene mi Windows usando C++?

Tags: c++

Hola quiero hacer un pequeño programa que compruebe si mi windows es de 64 o 32 bits y luego me muestre si lo es o no lo es. Por ejemplo:

```
#if_WIN64
 isWow64=true;

#elif_WIN32
 isWow64=false;

if(isWow64==true){
 windows="Windows64bits";
}else{
 windows="Windows32bits";
}
```

Lo que pasa que la manera en que lo hago es incorrecta ya que comprobará por mi aplicación. Como podría hacer para que comprobase si de verdad mi windows es de 32 o 64 independientemente de la aplicación y luego lo mostraré en consola.
Ej:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La solución que veo mejor es usar isWow64 y que devuelva verdadero o falso y a partir de ese valor verificar con un if si es de 32 o 64. Como puedo actualizar mi programa para que compruebe correctamente que arquitectura de windows tengo?.

Answer (score 0):

La API de Windows tiene una función llamada [GetVersion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/windows/desktop/ms724439(v=vs.85).aspx) que precisamente arrojará esta información.

Ejemplo:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

void main()
{
    DWORD dwVersion = 0; 
    DWORD dwMajorVersion = 0;
    DWORD dwMinorVersion = 0; 
    DWORD dwBuild = 0;

    dwVersion = GetVersion();

    // Get the Windows version.

    dwMajorVersion = (DWORD)(LOBYTE(LOWORD(dwVersion)));
    dwMinorVersion = (DWORD)(HIBYTE(LOWORD(dwVersion)));

    // Get the build number.

    if (dwVersion < 0x80000000)              
        dwBuild = (DWORD)(HIWORD(dwVersion));

    printf("Version is %d.%d (%d)\n", 
                dwMajorVersion,
                dwMinorVersion,
                dwBuild);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

En la documentación de la API `IsWow64Process` tienes un ejemplo de cómo hacerlo:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684139(v=vs.85).aspx

Observa que para que el resultado obtenido en `Wow64Process` tenga el sentido que necesitas, tu aplicación debe estar compilada como una aplicación de 32 bits.

> **Wow64Process [out]**
>
> A pointer to a value that is set to TRUE if the process is running
>   under WOW64. If the process is running under 32-bit Windows, the value
>   is set to FALSE. If the process is a 64-bit application running under
>   64-bit Windows, the value is also set to FALSE.

[que en mi traducción más que libre sería algo como]

> **Wow64Process [out]**
>
> Un puntero a un valor que será puesto en TRUE si el proceso se está ejecutando bajo WOW64. Si el proceso se ejecutase bajo Windows de 32 bits, el valor sería puesto a FALSE. Si el proceso fuera una aplicación de 64 bits ejecutándose bajo un Windows de 64 bits, ese valor también sería puesto en FALSE.